# What's the reason of conflict of UITableView‘s TapGestureRecognizer and it's superview's TapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

[image: picture1]

In the picture1, the green view have 2 subviews,the button and the tableview.The green view has a UITapGestureRecognizer。When i tap button,the button can normal response, but when tap tableview's cell the green view's UITapGestureRecognizer will response, the tableview's delegate function didSelectRowAtIndexPath not response.I know how to solve this problem,but i want to know what mechanism lead to the problem. Who can tell me?Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you have any cells in the table? From the pictures it looks like not, so there are no rows selected, because you didn't add any

Comment: @JackRobinson the cell with gray background color is